# C# separate the words in a text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file with many words separated by `;`. It looks like this:

```
eye;hand;mouth;arms;book
three;head;legs;home
```

I would like to go through this file and search for the symbol `;` and modify the file so that every word is transposed with line break.

Should I read the text file in a string first with,

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Then check:

```
if readText.contains(";");
```

But I don't know what to do next

Comment: use readText,Replace(";",Environment.NewLine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
var result = readText.Replace(";", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
readText.Replace(";",Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
string g = readText.Replace(";", "\n");
```